# How to call direct REST call on Google api php client library?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-php-client, zend-gdata

Is this any possible to call post,put,get,delete methods directly on new Google Api php client library . For example in Zend gdata provide 
get(URL),
Post(URL,content body) I need to call like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Google_Http_Request`](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Http/Request.php):

```
$request = new Google_Http_Request($url, $method, $headers, $postBody);
$client->execute($request);
```